# Loading modal-dialog from <a> Also .Show() might not be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am fairly new to web development. I have this problem.. It is probably something simple but I can't seem to work it out.

I solved how to use a link to run some javascript. The javascript is supposed to open a modal but the script doesn't work.

To call my script I am using this: (I confirmed this works because I had placed an 'alert()' in the script to test if it went through)

```
<li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showBugForm()">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bug"></i> Report a Bug
    </a>
</li>
```

The script being called is:

```
function showBugForm(){
    $('#repBug').modal('show');}
```

The main structure of my modal is shown below. I know the modal doesn't have any problems since I was able to load modal from a button, but I can't seem do it properly from an  element. For the sake of context: I was able to load the modal by adding 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#repBug"' to my button attributes, but I can't do the same with html link tag.)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="repBug" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
                   <!-- Here's my Code -->
        <div>
    <div>
<div>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Please ask your question properly.. In question you never mentioned php and two separate file. You didn't even mentioned php tag in tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-target="#repBug" data-toggle="modal" href="#repBug"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bug"></i> Report a Bug</a>
```

Try this, it will solve your problem .Calling any function is not required here. Your modal will open directly on click of this anchor tag.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer provided by me , please select it as a correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was because I missed to add:

```
<?php include_once('bug-form.php'); ?>
```

To my index.php file .. Because I had the code written in  different php file named 'bug-form.